# How to make the chart content area take up the maximum area available to it?

Tags: java, javafx, charts

Pretty straight forward question: **How to make the chart content area take up the maximum area available to it?**

I'm using JavaFX. In my case I want to have many AreaCharts based on true/false `yAxis` (0/1). Unfortunatelly I can't find a solution how to change content height of these charts using method like `setMaxHeight` or `setPrefHeight` on yAxis or AreaChart objects.

I've already tried few answers from SO, but none of them works.

Here's a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

Any hints or tips?

Comment: What do you mean "Change height of these charts below region height"? What region are you referring to? What does "below" mean in this context?

Comment: The problem is that using methods like "setMaxHeight" or "setPrefHeight" on yAxis object doesn't affect height for values below 150.

Comment: Load your chart up in [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) and debug it's layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Restated Question*

Your question is bit unclear but this is what I think you are asking is:

**How to make the chart content area take up the maximum area available to it?**

Perhaps it is not that, but anyway that is the question I am answering here.

*Sample Output*

Here is a screen shot of a small chart:

[image: small chart]

The chart has all axes, legends, titles and padding around the content removed.  This allows the chart content to take up all of the available space, making display of very small charts possible.  By default, the padding title and axis display would take up sufficient room that the chart content itself becomes illegible for very small charts.

*Sample Code*

In the code below, lots of things are have their visibility set to false and the preferred size of the axes is set to 0:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class AreaChartSample extends Application {

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws URISyntaxException, MalformedURLException {
        stage.setTitle("Area Chart Sample");
        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 31, 1);
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 28, 1);

        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        xAxis.setPrefSize(0, 0);
        yAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        yAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        yAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        yAxis.setPrefSize(0, 0);

        final AreaChart<Number,Number> ac = 
            new AreaChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

        ac.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(false);
        ac.setVerticalGridLinesVisible(false);
        ac.setLegendVisible(false);
        ac.setVerticalZeroLineVisible(false);
        ac.setHorizontalZeroLineVisible(false);

        ac.getStylesheets().add(
                getClass().getResource("unpad-chart.css").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()
        );

        XYChart.Series seriesApril= new XYChart.Series();
        seriesApril.setName("April");
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 4));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 10));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 8));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 5));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 13));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 19));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 21));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(30, 21));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(31, 19));

        XYChart.Series seriesMay = new XYChart.Series();
        seriesMay.setName("May");
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 13));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 12));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 14));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 23));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 26));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(31, 26));

        Scene scene  = new Scene(ac,80,60);
        ac.getData().addAll(seriesApril, seriesMay);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Also, some CSS removes padding.  Place the CSS file in the same location as `AreaChartSample.java` and have your build system copy it to the build target directory.

*unpad-chart.css*

```
.chart {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
.chart-content {
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
.axis {
    AXIS_COLOR: transparent;
}
.axis:top > .axis-label,
.axis:left > .axis-label {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
.axis:bottom > .axis-label,
.axis:right > .axis-label {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

*Layout debugging advice*

- To debug layout issues, use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).
- To determine default CSS styles to override, review `modena.css`:

  - for Java 8, `modena.css` is inside the `jfxrt.jar` file that ships with your JRE.