# How is it possible to reduce the size of a JavaFX Chart so it fits into a ListCell?

Tags: java, css, javafx, linechart

I'm building a JavaFX application and I want to put several very small `LineChart` into a `ListView` to get something like this:
[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH2NR.jpg)

In my current attempts I've managed to get the charts correctly inside the ListView but so far I've failed to fit them to the desired size: [What it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcr1f.png)

Here is my custom ListCell implementation:

```
//similar to:
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151281/javafx-linechart-as-a-cell-in-treetableview
public class ChartListCell extends ListCell<LineChart.Series> {

    private CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    private NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    private LineChart<String, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    public ChartListCell() {
        //a bunch of visual configuration similar to 
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005870/how-to-make-the-chart-content-area-take-up-the-maximum-area-available-to-it

        chart.setMaxHeight(17.0);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(XYChart.Series item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        } else {
            setGraphic(chart);
            if (!chart.getData().contains(item))
                chart.getData().setAll(item);
        }
    }
}
```

CSS styling to remove padding:

```
.chart{
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
.chart-content{
    -fx-padding: 0px;
}
.chart-series-line{
    -fx-stroke-width: 2px;
    -fx-effect: null;
    -fx-stroke: #009682;
}
.axis{
    AXIS_COLOR: transparent;
}
.axis:top > .axis-label,
.axis:left > .axis-label {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
.axis:bottom > .axis-label,
.axis:right > .axis-label {
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

The cell is bound to an `ObservableList<XYChart.Series>`.
When I try to call `this.setPrefHeight(17);` on the cell everything breaks and the Chart is no longer visible.

Comment: It might actually be easier just to create your own graphic for this (`Pane` with a `Path` or collection of `Line`s), instead of trying to reuse a line chart.

Comment: That was kind of what I was trying to avoid :D

Comment: Have you tried it? It's probably not much more code than you have already posted just to get something simple working.

Comment: I might try it tomorrow if no one comes up with any other ideas till then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `snapshot` method from the `Node` class to get a `WriteableImage` of each chart and show that in your ListCell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this helps a bit and I'll use this method for now.However, I'd like to be able to use some functionality from the `LineChart` class like tooltips which I can't if I convert it to an image.